# I want to have the textbox value by default 1 and increment in the next record

Tags: c#

```
textbox1.text=1;
```

My question is, I want to have by default the textbox1 value 1 and then increment it in the record by default.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not clear.

Comment: Thats not really a question. You want to default the value to 1, and then save it as 2? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood what you want but if you need your textbox to always default to 1 you should create your own textbox class extending the UI.TextBox (don't know if you are in Web or Win).

Something like this:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
   private string text = "1";
   public override string Text
   {
     get {return text;}
     set {text = value};
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood you correctly. Not sure whetehr its web or win either.

I am just rewriting what i understood "There is a default textbox whose value should be 1, and for the rest of the records from database more textboxes should come dynamically with values for it incremented by 1 from previous"

If its web you can use some javascript to initialize a variable to 1. Then while generating textboxes you probably can set its value with variable value and increment the variable value for next record.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:
1. Setting it in design mode. Like this,

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

2. Setting it in you code behind in the Page_Load event handler. Like this

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
          txtName.Text = "1";
      }

But you should remember to convert these values to integer before incrementing it. Like this

```
int myValue = Convert.ToInt32(txtName.Text);
```

Then you can increment it and assign it back to the textbox.

There are other option available like the OnInit event handler. I guess this will do.